# Doubling Time for certain bacteria

Tags: logarithms

Say a culture of bacteria doubles in weight every 24 hours. If it originally weighed 10g, what would be its weight after 18 hours?

I know how to calculate half-life but don't know about doubling time. What is the easiest formula to use in order to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the initial weight is $10$g, and the weight doubles every $24$ hours, you know that after $t$ hours the weight will have doubled $\frac{t}{24}$ times. Thus, if $w(t)$ is the weight after $t$ hours, we must have

$$w(t)=10\cdot2^{t/24}\;.\tag{1}$$

You want $w(18)$, so just substitute $t=18$ into $(1)$.

Note that this is exactly the way that half-lives behave, but with a power of $2$ (for doubling) instead of a power of $\frac12$ (for halving). That is, if the half-life were $24$ hours, the weight after $t$ hours would be

$$10\left(\frac12\right)^{t/24}\;.$$

Thus, it’s not really anything new. You should be able to work just as will with a tripling time, or the time it takes for a reduction to one-tenth of the weight, or any similar way of giving a rate of geometric growth or decay.

Comment: For calculating half-lives, I like to use the formula ln(1/2)= -kt1/2. So you're saying that I can just replace that 1/2 with a 2 for doubling time?

Comment: @jaykirby: I’m not sure how to read your -kt1/2. In any case, the present problem isn’t analogous to finding a half-life, since you’re *given* the doubling time.

Comment: so what formula would you recommend I use for calculating doubling time?

Comment: @jaykirby: Depends on what data you’re given. Exactly what kind of problem do you have in mind?

Comment: Same kind of problem like the one here.

Comment: @jaykirby: As I said before, this is **not** a problem in which you are to calculate the doubling time. You’re **given** the doubling time and asked to use it to find the  weight after $18$ hours; formula $(1)$ allows you to find the weight after $t$ hours for any $t$.